# KineticJS - Rescaling images/shapes after zoom

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

So basically I have an application which zooms in by scaling every layer and adjusting the position of the layers. However I have a bunch of circles (and images) on some layers which I need to keep the size the same regardless of the zoom level (ie regardless of the scale of the layer).

Is there a way to set the scale of every shape/image in a layer without iteration? I've looked at using a Group but there is no universal way to set a universal scale.

If not, would there be an efficient way to do this without iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the non-scaling objects in a separate group and then rescale (and optionally reposition) that group based on the scaling factor of the groups layer.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2X7eK/

```
var scaleFactor=2;

// scale the entire layer by 2X

layer.setScale(scaleFactor);

// unscale just the noGroup back to original size

noGroup.setScale(1/scaleFactor);

// reposition just the noGroup back to it's original position
// before the layer was resized

noGroup.setPosition(noGroup.getX()/scaleFactor,noGroup.getY()/scaleFactor);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe your solution does not perform a zoom, rather it reproduces the same image as the stage without zoom by scaling both the layer and the group (one can think of a group as a sub-layer), which counteract each other. What I need is when a user zooms in, the distance between the shapes/images increases, however their sizes stay the same (in a more conventional zoom, both the size of the shape/image and the distance would increase).

Comment: Assuming you have 2 kinds of objects on a layer (1) some desired to scale and (2) some desired to not scale.  In this case, all the items on the layer will be scaled but the noScaleGroup will be unscaled to original size.  Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. What I need is a zoom operation that performs exactly the same as a normal zoom would (increases size and distance between shapes), except I need the sizes of the shapes to be a fixed constant regardless of the zoom level (say 25x25). Scaling a group does not do the job as it reduces the distance between shapes as well.

Comment: That's what I meant by "and optionally reposition" in my answer.  If you want the noScaleGroup to be in the same screen position (as opposed to its scaled position), you should reposition the group by changing it's x/y coordinates by 1/scaleFactor also.  Cheers!

Comment: Wouldn't that just reposition the entire group itself? By scaling the layer by scaleFactor, and scaling the group by 1/scaleFactor, the distance would appear to be the same both before and after the zoom (for the no scale shapes)? However in a real zoom, the distance between the shapes would be larger. Sorry if I still don't get your solution.

Comment: Yes, the entire noScaleGroup is visually the same size and at the same position as before the scaling of the layer.  **Any shapes not in the noScaleGroup have been resized and repositioned.**  To explain, I've added further code to my answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to solve my problem in KineticJS. However this answer is a good answer to a similar problem.